# What's the difference between network-manager.service and NetworkManager.service in Systemd?

Tags: networking, network-manager, systemd

I can't seem to be able to Google this easily and I'm not exactly sure where to find more information.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and my Systemd shows both `network-manager.service` and `NetworkManager.service`. Are both of these based on the `network-manager` program or is this something else?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference.

The unit file for `network-manager.service` is a symlink to `NetworkManager.service`.

```
$ file $(locate network-manager.service)
/lib/systemd/system/network-manager.service: symbolic link to NetworkManager.service
```

The "two" services are the same process:

```
$ systemctl status NetworkManager
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-05-28 06:51:58 BST; 25min ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 667 (NetworkManager)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           ├─ 667 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
           └─1277 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-wlan0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient

$ systemctl status network-manager
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-05-28 06:51:58 BST; 25min ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 667 (NetworkManager)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           ├─ 667 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
           └─1277 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-wlan0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient
```

The name `network-manager` remains simply for compatibility, so people can use old style commands like `sudo service network-manager restart` (sympathy for our muscle memory).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I seem to be getting a different result. `sudo systemctl status network-manager.service` returns `active` while `sudo systemctl status NetworkManager.service` returns `inactive(dead)`

Comment: o.O *mind blown*. Do you want to [paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com) your full results?

Comment: I was just in the process of reinstalling the network manager so that's most likely why it shows as `inactive(dead)` [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/7GTDZCR) .

Comment: thanks for the update @Rtsne42 my tranquility is restored :D

Comment: It seems that this can not be used anymore:  

$ sudo service network-manager restart

Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.