# Where has the network-manager service in 21.10 gone?

Tags: network-manager

Before upgrading I could use `sudo service network-manager restart` when having connection issues. After upgrading to 21.10 the network-manager is still installed, but not as a service anymore. Restarting the "networking" service instead seems not to have the same effects (and didn't had before in 20.04).

How do I restart the network-manager in 21.10?

Comment: From [the package file list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/network-manager/filelist), it looks like it's `NetworkManager.service` now, in line with how it's in other distros.

Comment: @muru Tried it, seems not to exist under this name :-( `sudo service NetworkManager.service status` "Unit NetworkManager.service.service could not be found."

Comment: I see the `service` cmd has a `--status-all` flag which allows to retrieve a list of all services. Network manager is not listed there, only "networking" again. Seems there's no service for it anymore or it has been consolidated and working differently now somehow.

Comment: After taking a look at the files in the list @muru has linked, I see in /lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service: `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon`. What I now do to restart it is `sudo killall NetworkManager` + `sudo NetworkManager --no-daemon &`. Seems to do what the service restart did before.

Comment: See the output from your first command: `NetworkManager.service.service` with two `.service`s in it. When using the `service` command, you shouldn't put have `.service` `sudo service NetworkManager status`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The NetworkManager service has been named `NetworkManager` for a [while now](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/amd64/network-manager/filelist), and `network-manager` service was kept around as a backwards-compatibility option (see [What's the difference between network-manager.service and NetworkManager.service in Systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/919609/158442)). It looks like that was finally dropped in Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla), and now only the `NetworkManager` name remains. You can use it like so:

```
sudo service NetworkManager start|stop|...
sudo systemctl start|stop|... NetworkManager
sudo systemctl start|stop|... NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: As all Linux things, this is case sensitive so `NetworkManager ` works but `networkmanager` does not and will reply `Unit file networkmanager.service does not exist`. This is pretty confusing as all services on ubuntu last MANY years have all been lowercase and I always type lowercase. Luckily I've used copy/paste from your answer, so you get my upvote, but you may want to update the answer with they case sensitive notice. Thanks!